# How to format Vue.compile and render errors?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a little component editor and try to render it real time. I have problems with handling Vue.compile and render errors.

Here is the component editor (https://jsfiddle.net/gecjfk1w/5/):

```
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="some_text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

  <div>
    The rendered component:
    <component :is="component"></component>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
const ComponentFactory = (template) => {
    return {
    template
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    some_text: `<div>Hello World</div>`
  },
  computed: {
    component () {
        return ComponentFactory(this.some_text)
    }
  }
})
```

Try to update the textarea with `<div>Hello World {{ hello }}</div>`

You will see in the console the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "hello" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render
```

This is normal behavior but I'd like to display something when this error appears.

Like: `"An error have been detected: {{ error }}"`

I have tried the `renderError` function on the `ComponentFactory` and the `errorCaptured` hook on the parent element (https://jsfiddle.net/gecjfk1w/5/) with no success.

However, the `renderError` and `errorCaptured` methods work well when the error is not a compile error:

Example: `<div>Hello World {{ hello.f }}</div>` throws a `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'f' of undefined"` and activates `renderError` and `errorCaptured`.

However, I'm not even sure that renderError should be used because the documentation says that it is not available in production mode.

**How could I catch compile and render errors? It would be like a try/catch on the template level**

Comment: The message you referenced, `Property or method "hello" is not defined`, is not a compilation error. If you're seeing that message then template compilation succeeded. That warning is logged during rendering in non-production builds but it isn't actually a rendering error as such. Even though the property is missing the rendering will succeed. If you want to write something as ambitious as a component editor then you're going to have to get deep into the Vue source to understand how all this works. e.g. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.11/src/core/instance/proxy.js

Comment: I actually succeeded to make it work by using the errorCaptured hook for TypeErrors and by checking the name of the component by using Vue.compile first and checking the name of the component. If its name is "noop", then the compilation has failed.